# Meteor bootstrap modal not rendering correct data when having more then one modal element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a meteor collocation returning each in my template for each item I have a modal setup. The modal works fine however it's always loading the same data. I'm thinking my approach is a bit in correct. Here is the setup

My first template just has this

```
{{> blocksList}}
```

In blocksLists I have the following

```
{{#each blocks}}
 {{> blockItem}}
{{/each}}
```

And for blockItem

```
<template name="blockItem">
  {{> blockModal}}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <section class="panel panel-featured-left panel-featured-nav-color">
            <a style="cursor: pointer"   id="open-modal">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="widget-summary">
                        <div class="widget-summary-col widget-summary-col-icon">
                            <div class="summary-icon bg-nav-color">
                                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is the template helper

```
Template.blockItem.events = {
  "click #open-modal" : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#blockModal").modal("show");
  }
};
```

And finally the modal JS, the template is a basic bootstrap modal

```
Template.blockModal.helpers({
  getOrganicFieldStatusTo:function(){
    console.log(this.organicFieldStatusTo);
    if(this.organicFieldStatusTo != null){
      moment.locale(TAPi18n.getLanguage());
      return moment(this.organicFieldStatusTo).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
    } else {
     return false
    }
  }
});


Template.blockModal.rendered = function () {

  var longitude =  this.data.longitude;
  var latitude =  this.data.latitude;
  var _id = this.data.productionUnitCode + this.data.subCode;
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    console.log(this);
    initialize(longitude, latitude, _id);
  });
};

function initialize(longitude, latitude, _id) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(longitude,latitude);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+ ' ID: ' + _id + ' longitude: ' + longitude + ' latitude: ' + latitude + '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: ''
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    $('#blockModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

      lastCenter=map.getCenter();
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      map.setCenter(lastCenter);
    });
  });
}
```

Ok updated I figured out when I was firing the click event I was not loading the correct modal I fixed that by doing the following

```
"click #open-modal" : function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var block ='#blockModal' + this.productionUnitCode;
    console.log(this.productionUnitCode);
  $(block).modal("show");
  }
```

Only issue with this approach I'm creating the modal template per item which seems a waste and not good for performance especially if I have 10 or 15 items. I'm thinking there needs to be a better approach for this.

Comment: For my bootstrap modals I use https://github.com/pahans/reactive-modal. It is very simple and with the use of a generic function you can create the specific modal when it is needed.

Comment: I tried it had some issues and it's not clear how pass data to the modal the examples just has how to get the values in the modal. The docs are also a bit poor